# A quote from The Lord of The flies

Tags: word-usage, sentence

There's a sentence within a novel that I don't understand. Can you break it down for me?

> The boy with fair hair lowered himself down the last few feet of rock
>   and began to pick his way toward the lagoon. Though he had taken off
>   his school sweater and trailed it now from one hand, his grey shirt
>   stuck to him and his hair was plastered to his forehead. *All round
>   him the long scar smashed into the jungle was a bath of heat*

What scar? Is the scar "the bath of heat"?
Why does it say *all round* and not "all around"?

Comment: I'm sure it could be explained by the surrounding context which might help explain what the 'scar' might be. I don't have the entire text with me for this literary interpretation. The 'bath of heat' is a metaphor, as though you are swimming in a liquid bath of something, that thing being heat. 'All round' sounds OK (a bit old-fashioned?) as an alternative to 'all around'

Comment: I think the "scar" was the path made through the trees by the crashing airplane.

Comment: The long "scar" might be the path the plane that crashed down cut into the jungle of the island.

Comment: If you search the site for "bath of heat" you will find a number of questions about this sentence.

Comment: @Mitch Actually it's the first paragraph of the book. It is a bit strange, but I think wanting to find out about the *scar*, make sense of it, is what provides the suspense that propels us to keep reading.